# Installing ArcGIS Pro and ArcMap at same time on same laptop

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-pro, installation

I want to install ArcGIS Pro and ArcMap at the same time.

Are there any problems using them on the same laptop?

Answer (score 3):

This is an ArcGIS Pro [Frequently Asked Question](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/get-started/faq.htm#anchor3):

> **Can ArcGIS Pro be installed on a machine with ArcMap?**
>
> Yes, you can install ArcGIS Pro on the same machine as ArcMap and
>   other ArcGIS Desktop applications, or on a machine without ArcMap or
>   any other Esri products.